# How to automate in selenium using Java

Tags: java, selenium

I am newbie to java with selenium. How to write more generic code on below requirement?

Test Case : Search for doctors using keywords

1. Go to www.medinfi.com
2. Select locality AECS, Bangalore (Locality input should be dynamic, i.e. it should be able to change the test data at any time)
3. Enter search keyword “shai” in the 2nd search box for doctor/hospital name. (search keyword should be dynamic)
4. Validate the output in the dropdown against expected output data set

package com.medinfi.code;

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

   public class MedinfiChallenge {

  private WebDriver driver;
   @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
   public void setUp() throws Exception
   {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\SeleniumProject\\Medinfi\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.medinfi.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

   @Test
   public void testMedinfi() throws Exception 
   {
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='city-locality1']")).sendKeys("AECS Layout, Bengaluru");
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ip1_text1']")).sendKeys("Hospitals");
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"searchIcon\"]")).click();

   }

   @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
   public void tearDown() throws Exception 
   {
       driver.quit();
   }

   }
```

Comment: Have a look on tutorials https://www.airpair.com/selenium/posts/selenium-tutorial-with-java

Answer (score -1):

To make your code more generic and can be used to automated test you must put all the setting code to a file (usually use excel file in real world) and read from that file. These info include: driver path, link to web need to be tested, xpath... These are generic information will change frequently because you are not test 1 website or 1 link, you need to test multiple site, each site have specific xpath to test. There is a framework for you reference the [Open2Test](http://www.open2test.org/) you can get the source code and learn the way they do.

Comment: Thank you for your response. can you please look into my code, if anything wrong then suggest me.

Comment: Your original question is how to generic your code, I have presented the way to you. Your code above is not seem to be wrong, but it's only as a demo version because all things is hard code.